# What else is being done to make these biscuits

Tags: biscuits

I am looking for a basic Biscuit recipe, and found the one on the Bisquick web site. Looks fairly basic. Too basic to make the biscuits pictured. There are distinct ridging on the tops and the browning looks too defined not be something like butter or egg.

So, would additionally would i have to do to get the same look? Or is this just a picture of plastic rolls?
http://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/bisquick-rolled-biscuits/3e0c95f0-8aec-4a01-9463-73759b2ce066

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is highly likely those biscuits benefited from the skills of a [food stylist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_photography).

They will have used any number of techniques to ensure the biscuits look as good as possible for the photo, possibly including some that would render them poor tasting or even inedible.

Among the things they might have done are:

- Controlling the lighting to put the biscuits at their best appearance
- Using a blow torch to carefully brown each biscuit individually in the most attractive way possible
- Painstakingly cutting hundreds of biscuits with a fancy cutter and selecting the few that came out looking perfect for further treatment
- Dabbing on flour with a paint brush to give them that rustic look

I am sure there are more tricks of the trade, but it is not something I do.

At home, you would achieve best results with a convection oven (if you have one), and a very sharp biscuit cutter (to not disturb the layers) used on biscuit dough that is properly and skillfully prepered to create the flaky layers.   Brushing the tops with milk or butter will also help them brown (and taste good).

Answer (score 6):

The 'ridges' are created by the [biscuit cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FLXBN2), browning may or may not be aided by an egg wash, but given the short bake time, I doubt it, if your biscuits don't brown evenly, rotate the pan 180° after 4 minutes.

(that said, yes, those in the picture are almost certainly props...)